# .htaccess - не работает правило

Tags: url, .htaccess, чпу

Здравствуйте!
Стоит задача есть такие урлы

```
http://localhost/index.php?url=article&id=55
```

Хочу их преобразовать в

```
http://localhost/article/id/55
```

или

```
http://localhost/article/55
```

Пробовал

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ /?url=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Не получается, как правильно установить правило для этого? Знаю можно сделать так

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

и разбивать запрос, но возможно сделать так как я сначала писал?

Comment: У вас `\` перед `$` лишний

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?url=$1&id=$2 [L]

Comment: @likerRr, спасибо, только есть еще вопрос. 

Сейчас открывается так
http://localhost/login/

а так нет

http://localhost/login

как сделать что бы и так и так открывался? Заранее спасибо! Сделайте ваш комментарий ответом.

Comment: пока решил так

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?url=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?url=$1&id=$2 [L]

насколько правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного изменил ваше начальное правило, чтобы в id попадали только цифры (что логично).
Имя раздела (articles, например) тоже следует однозначно обозначить [a-zA-Z0-9_-].
Плюс, чтобы у вас подобный механизм реализации ЧПУ работал корректно, нужно использовать квантификатор **+**, а не *****, не допускающий пустого значения.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Если указан только раздел
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[/]?$ /?url=$1 [QSA,L]
# Если указан раздел и id
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[/](\d+)[/]?$ /?url=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

---

**[/]?** - указывает на то, что адрес может быть как со слэшем в конце, так и без него.

Зачем используется флаг **QSA**

> 'qsappend|QSA' (добавлять строку
> запроса) - **Query String Append**
>
> Этот флаг указывает механизму
> преобразований на добавление а не
> замену, строки запроса из URL к
> существующей, в строке подстановки.
> Используйте это когда вы хотите
> добавлять дополнительные данные в
> строку запроса с помощью директив
> преобразований.

Comment: @VenZell, у меня ваше правило выдает 404

Comment: @alex159, на каком примере?

Comment: @VenZell, все еще раз перечитал. Работает, только вот насчет  квантификатора +.
Он лишний, так как эта часть будет не обязательна

Comment: @alex159, чтобы все корректно работало с необязательным слэшем, лучше сделать так, как указал я сейчас в обновленном ответе.  
Иначе, теоретически, у вас могут быть ситуации, когда GET-параметры url или id будут пустыми.

Comment: Можно обойтись одним правилом:

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?(\d+)?/?$ /?url=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

А в чем проблема того, что параметры url или id могут быть пустыми? Разработчику в том или ином случае придется проверить: 

  1. Установлены ли они вообще
  2. Пустые ли они (чтобы не составлять лишние условия на выборку)